# Can I rate-limit requests to Parse.com on a per-user basis?

Tags: security, parse-platform

I'm developing an app using Parse.com for BaaS. Aside from regular security checks, it's my understanding/philosophy that part of security is to assume someone HAS broken in, and then limit the amount they can access/delete/mess up.

One way I'd like to do this is to have a per-user rate limit on certain API requests. I can imagine a sort of naive method where I keep a list of who has accessed recently and when, and check that list before allowing a request of that type to go through (I'm thinking beforeSave for various custom classes).

Is there a better, ideally built-in way?

Answer (score 2):

Though Parse.com doesn't have options for configuring this, parse claims that they keep track of suspicious activities and attempt for DDoS attacks are monitored. But not sure to what extend this is possible, because this specific problem is scenario wise relevant/irrelevant.
You dont have an option to do user level rate limit, but they will report any suspicious activities found like redundant hits from same device.

Comment: @buildsucceeded, please Accept as correct, if you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As given in the Parse docs [here](https://parse.com/docs/data#security-classes), They support two levels of permissions, [*Class level*](https://parse.com/docs/data#security-classes) (via Data browser) & [*Object level*](https://parse.com/docs/data#security-objects) (using ACLs)

> **Configuring class-level permissions**
>
> Parse lets you specify what operations are allowed per class. This
> lets you restrict the ways in which clients can access or modify your
> classes. To change these settings, go to the Data Browser, select a
> class, open the "More" dropdown, and click the "Set permissions" item.

Class level permissions is a manual way of giving access to specific users or roles on a class.

In your case, you might probably need object level permissions based on Access Control Lists(ACL).

> **Access Control Lists**
>
> The idea behind an ACL is that each object has a list of users and roles along with what permissions that user or
> role has. A user needs read permissions (or must belong to a role that
> has read permissions) in order to retrieve an object's data, and a
> user needs write permissions (or must belong to a role that has write
> permissions) in order to update or delete that object

Create a new role and add list of users to that role who can access. Then set an ACL like this on the other objects.

```
{ "role:YourRoleName":{"read":true, "write" : true}}
```

You can now dynamically add or remove users in that role without updating individual objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer-- edited my question to make it clear that I'm asking about rate limiting, not ACLs. That was clear in my mind but not, in retrospect, in the question.

Comment: Ah, missed that. I don't think there is any built-in support for rate limiting.